# Como inserir fontes especificas no CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Meu cliente passou fontes específicas para um site. Estas estão em formato TTF.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou acostumado a usar as fontes do Google e não há elas lá.

Como posso utilizar estas fontes em meu CSS ou HTML?

Comment: Se for essa da listagem acima, tem aqui: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway - TTF preparado para uso desktop não é necessariamente o formato mais adequado nem eficiente para CSS. E se for usar uma fonte que não é licenciada para uso free, lembre-se de tomar as devidas providências para licenciar corretamente.

Comment: Fontes TTF não funcionam no IE e nem no Safari.

Comment: @Bacco pode colocar o seu como resposta, que deu mais certo. Assim marco como resposta certa. Obrigado.

Comment: @Ramos a solução já se encontra no link de fechamento acima, mas a sua pergunta servirá de índice para ajudar outras pessoas que pesquisarem por palavras chaves similares. Ainda bem que deu certo, qualquer dúvida abra uma nova questão ou comentário.

Comment: Bom, pela sua escolha, acho que a pergunta deveria ser `Onde acho essas fontes?` e não `Como posso utilizar estas fontes em meu CSS ou HTML?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publique suas fonts no servidor. Exemplo `raleway-bold.ttf`

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ralewayExtralight;
    src: url(raleway-extralight.ttf);
}


@font-face {
    font-family: ralewayBold;
    src: url(raleway-bold.ttf);
}

.Extralight {
    font-family: ralewayExtralight;
}

.Bold {
    font-family: ralewayBold;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="Extralight">Estilo de font importada: raleway-extralight.ttf</p>

<p class="Bold">Estilo de font importada: raleway-bold.ttf</p>
```

### Aparência nos navegadores:

**Google Chrome:**

[image: Google Chrome]

**Firefox:**

[image: Firefox]

**Opera:**

[image: Opera]

**Safari:**

[image: Safari]

**Internet Explorer:**

[image: IE]